# How toConvert minutes into hours in postgresql

Tags: postgresql

I'm new in PostgreSQL I need to convert the minute's value in a column into hours and minutes format I have searched in various sources but failed to achive.Some one please help me to achieve this.
In mean while I try to use to_char() as follows :

```
UPDATE tablename SET col2 = TO_CHAR(((col1*60 ||`second`))::interval, ‘HH24:MI:SS’) where id = 145;
```

but I get the following error...

> ```
>     column "late_by" is of type timestamp with time zone but expression is of type text
> LINE 2: UPDATE attendance SET late_by = TO_CHAR(((lateby*60 || 'seco...
>                                         ^
> HINT:  You will need to rewrite or cast the expression.
> ```

Comment: I'd say interval data type fits better for field `late_by`

Comment: Please **[EDIT]** your question and the `create table` statement, the **real** statement you are using (the one you have shown is invalid) some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [**no screen shots**](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). **[edit]** your question - do **not** post code or additional information in comments.

Comment: @VaoTsun I didn't get you what you said.please explain me in detail

Comment: try changing it like here `select (185||' seconds')::interval`

Answer (score 0):

your column `late_by` is of time timestamp, yet you want to update it with interval, not timestamp. If you want to save how much time somebody is late, better use `interval`, eg:

```
t=# create table w3 (t interval);
CREATE TABLE
t=# insert into w3 select (185||' seconds')::interval;
INSERT 0 1
t=# select * from w3;
    t
----------
 00:03:05
(1 row)
```

as you can see "conversion" to minutes done by postgres itself

Answer (score 0):

It is unclear what type each column in your statement is.

But if it helps, you can perform maths on intervals

```
select interval '60 seconds' * 15;
```

or in your case, if "col1" is integer: interval '60 seconds' * col1;